# Can you store a theorem number in a variable?

Tags: variables, latex

I use \newtheorem and the numbering is done automatically. Sometimes in the text I'll refer to a theorem by this number. I'd like to have a variable equal to this number, so if the theorem number changes, the references will change also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works through the usual `\label`/`\ref`-mechanism:

```
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:foo} ...

That was Theorem~\ref{thm:foo}
```

(You'll need two runs of LaTeX for the number to settle, you'll get a message about changed references.) Label commands "tack onto" certain things like section headers, captions, items of enumerations and, indeed, theorems and friends.

There are also extensions that can automatically distinguish sections from subsections or figures, for that, see hyperref's `\autoref` or the cleveref package, but don't worry about it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `\label` between the `\begin{yourtheorem} \end{yourtheorem}` and use `\ref` to refer to it as usual.

You can check [this link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/tips-theorems.html) for explanations with some broader context about theorems